# SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol methods not being called

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

In my .h file I have added the delegate as such:

```
@interface GameScene : SKScene<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
```

And in my .m file I have this

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{
     self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
}
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
     NSLog(@"contact");
}
```

I have nodes as well and they sometimes come into contact with one another. They have their physicsBody property rightfully set and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. What is wrong?Thanks!

Comment: Well, what you have shown is correct. You need to add some code related to creation and addition of your nodes. Also, show us how you have defined the bitmask values.

Comment: yup, specifically contact and category bitmasks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, how i solved it was making the contactTestBitMask on each node the opposite to the other.

It seems to jump into this method when both nodes have indicated their contactestbitmask to collide with each other.